# Will it be a called a closure as well, in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript

Consider the following code

```
() => {
    let amount = 0;

    return {
        inc_amount: () => amount + 100,
        dec_amount: () => amount - 100
    }
}
```

Will `amount` be considered a closure, provided that it is used in Object literal, and not in function. The code seem to work fine, in both cases, hence the question.

Comment: `() => ...` _is_ a function

Comment: In very simple terms closure means *ability of a function to access variable defined outside its scope.* So when you call this function directly, the variable should be still accessible and hence its stored in separate location. So if you see, `inc_amount` and `dec_amoiunt` are accessing `amount`, which is defined outside their scope. So yes they are closure

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It actually *is* used in (arrow) functions, which happen to be assigned to the properties of the object. And yes, it's a closure.

Answer (score 1):

The term 'closure' refers to the function plus the environment it wraps around - rather than saying `amount` is a closure, it'd be more correct to say that it's 'captured' *by* the closure.